# How to setup wired network connection in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking

I just installed Ubuntu, I cant get that how to set network connection, I don't have lancard driver for Ubuntu, help plz

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 1):

To setup a wired connection in Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10 or 12.04, click "Dash Home". Type Network Connections. Open the Network Connections window. You will see five tabs, between then "wired" is the first one. Click "Add" to setup a new wired connection. Provide the connection name (optional). Click "Save" if it is a DHCP connection. If your connection is static, then click on "IPv4 settings" tab. Fill up Address, Netmask, Gateway and DNS Server field and click "Save". Hope you can now enjoy your connection.

Comment: But I am doing this and it also showing that network connection established but when I am opening Firefox, it showing problem in loading pages! help

Comment: Can you tell me please, what type of connection are you using? Like Static, DHCP or DSL.